# Short story involving a future in which janitors run the world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I have been searching for a short story that I believe was from a paperback collection/anthology I read in the 60's-70's about a time traveler on his first trip, going forward to a futuristic city. The city is highly automated. He wanders around but the first person he talks to that seems to have a clue is a janitor/handyman. As I remember it, the protagonist pulls up to the place where he met the 'janitor' in a vehicle. He questions why a janitor/handyman is needed. It turns out that the 'janitors' run the world.

Was it a fever dream? Does anyone know what this story is?

Answer (score 13):

Could this be [The Marching Morons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Marching_Morons) by [Cyril M. Kornbluth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyril_M._Kornbluth)?
First published in Galaxy magazine, April 1951, it was included in [The Science Fiction Hall of Fame, Volume Two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Science_Fiction_Hall_of_Fame,_Volume_Two).  In this story, the "time traveler" was a cold sleeper from the 1980's.

> In 1988, real estate agent and con artist John Barlow is placed in
> suspended animation after a freak accident. He is revived in the
> distant future, in a confusing world filled with hypersexualized
> advertisements, vapid entertainment, and people who exhibit erratic,
> nonsensical behavior. Shortly after being revived, Barlow is
> introduced to two men who tell him that the current state of society
> is the fault of the "morons," the world's vast population of
> unintelligent people, who greatly outnumber the much smaller
> population of intelligent people.
>
> These men explain to Barlow that the most urgent crisis of their time
> is the population problem ("Poprob"). Historically, people of higher
> intelligence often chose to have few children (or no children at all)
> for pragmatic reasons, while people of lower intelligence, compelled
> by their sex drives, had larger families and reproduced in greater
> numbers. By the far future era in which Barlow has awakened, this
> unbalanced trend has been carried to its logical extreme, with a total
> world population of five billion morons (with an average IQ of 45)
> living under the supervision of three million members of an elite,
> intellectual upper-class who secretly govern world affairs.

Project Gutenberg has a copy [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/51233/51233-h/51233-h.htm).

Together with [Frederik Pohl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederik_Pohl), Kornbluth later used this idea in their 1954 novel [Search the Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_the_Sky).  In this story, the intelligent elite hid in plain sight as janitors and bathroom attendants.

> Ross fished absently in his pocket. “The thing that bothers me, Doc,”
> he said, “is that I know there are intelligent people somewhere
> around. I even know what they’re doing, I bet. They’re doing exactly
> what I tried to do: acted as stupid as anybody else, or stupider. I’d
> make a guess,” he said, warming up, “that if we could just make a
> statistical analysis of the whole planet and find the absolute
> stupidest-seeming people of the lot, we’d——”
>
> He ran out of breath all at once. His eyes bulged.
>
> He looked at the men’s-room attendant, and at the ten-cent piece in
> his own hand.
>
> “You!” he breathed.
>
> The attendant’s face suddenly seemed to come to life. In a voice that
> was abruptly richer and deeper than before, the man said: “Yes. You
> had to find us yourself, you know.”

Project Gutenberg has a copy [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/52228/52228-0.txt).

Comment: You should delete the bit about "The Marching Morons;" it matches none of the details of the question.

Comment: This may be a case of conflation, in which case both sources may be relevant to the poster.

Comment: How can it be a conflation when there's nothing there from it?

Comment: OP said it was a short story (which Marching Morons is), whereas Search the Sky is a novel. OP also said 'he went forward in time to a city', which happens in Marching Morons, whereas Search the Sky involves a trip by FTL ship to various worlds, ending up on Earth. Looks like conflation to me.

Comment: Another story about a society secretly controlled by an old "custodian" in a sub-basement is "Dodkin's Job" by Jack Vance but that's not it, no time travel.

Comment: @user14111 Also Dodkin has no idea how much power he has. But that was my first thought on seeing the question's title!

Comment: Interesting to see the similarities between this story and Idiocracy.

Comment: Thank you for the references and comments. I checked out both quickly and they don't match my memory but they will make a good read (thanks again). I am (pretty) sure that the protagonist was trying out his time-machine. This did shuffle some neurons and I remember the protagonist pulling up to the place where he met the 'janitor' in a vehicle.